# Multidimensional array with unordered indexes in Python

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, unordered

I have subsets of a finite set of n members, {1, ..., n}, and the members of each subset have corresponding values (depending on which subset they come from) that need to be stored.

One could think of it as a 2D array where one axis is subsets and the other is members 1, ..., n.

To perform a lookup:

x is a subset of {1, ..., n}, y is an element of {1, ..., n}

input: (x, y)

output: value corresponding to (x, y)

In Python I've come up with an implementation that uses dictionaries of dictionaries. For example, 'A' is a dictionary of dictionaries. For frozenset x (frozen because it must be immutable), A[x] is a dictionary with keys = members of x, values = data for (x,y). A[x][y] = stored data for (x,y).

Does anyone have a more elegant way of implementing this? Or is there an approach that is more conventional?

Edit:
Example:

```
# n = 2
A = dict()
A[frozenset({1})] = {1: f(frozenset({1}), 1)}
A[frozenset({2})] = {2: f(frozenset({2}), 2)}
A[frozenset({1, 2})] = {1: f(frozenset({1, 2}), 1), 2: f(frozenset({1, 2}), 2)}
A[frozenset({1, 2})][2] = f(frozenset({1, 2}), 2)
```

Comment: Can you show us some code, and point out what actual problems with it you seek to resolve?

Comment: Yes, the problem is a Traveling Salesman algorithm. My code can be found here:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/197536/traveling-salesman-algorithm-dataset-inferences

Comment: I feel that my implementation might be overly complex and is preventing me from improving the algorithm.

Comment: We don't need your code as is. Wee need a [complete minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Oh I see, so you're trying to solve TSP, and you've already posted it on Code Review a few hours ago.  This question as it stands is not suitable for SO, better proceed with the Code Review post.

Comment: I've already completed the algorithm to solve TSP (at least every test case I can think of). I'm wondering if there is a canonical way to deal with this small part of that algorithm which is less complex than dictionaries of dictionaries.

Comment: RedEyed, John Zwinck, perhaps just disregard that I already have an implementation and let me know what you would implement or what you've seen implemented.

Comment: (1) Do the values of `A` change over time? Or is `A` just a cache of the results of `f`? (2) Does `A[x]` have a separate purpose, or could `A` just be a flat dictionary with pairs as keys, i.e. `A[(x, y)] = f(x, y)`?

Comment: The values do change. I calculate and store the values f(x,y) one by one.

Comment: I'm not sure you understood. *For a particular combination of x and y*, does f(x, y) have different values at different times in the program? In other words, does f(x, y) depend on values other than x and y, and do those other values change over time, requiring you to recalculate f(x, y) for the same x and y?

Comment: I just reviewed my code and I think it is indeed the case that the values never change. A single dictionary with ordered pair keys might be exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: In that case you should be able to forget about the dictionary entirely. Just apply `@lru_cache(maxsize=None)` to `f` and use `f` everywhere you would use `A`. Also, you should mention people with @ so they get notified. You're just lucky I checked this post now and then.